# Slim framework - protect all but one route

Tags: slim

Using the the slim frame work with the http basic authentication middleware and I would like to protect all routes except one. I have found ways to protect specific routes but not one to protect all but one route. For example `http://api.com/public/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the call() method of the middleware or recreate it (it's really just one file), to ignore the desired path with an if else statement on

```
$resourceUri = $req->getResourceUri();
```

https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras/blob/master/Middleware/HttpBasicAuth.php

Comment: I actually did this in my index by including or not including the middleware based on URI.